# Max or Top1 with Format Function SQL

Tags: sql, vba

Is there anyway I can include the Max or Top1 function into the below.

I'm trying to return the latest date value however due to the database returning date & time format I need to use the `FORMAT` syntax to correct this.

I've tried in both the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses but can't get it to work

```
sSql = "SELECT FORMAT(Total.StockDate, 'dd/mm/yy' ) AS DateRev FROM " & Mailbox & Totals & " WHERE(Total.UnitCode=" & Sheets("Pipe Cleaning").Range("C4") & " )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you *can* do it as a subquery:

```
sSql = "SELECT FORMAT(StockDate, 'dd/mm/yy' ) AS DateRev FROM " & _
       " (SELECT MAX(StockDate) StockDate FROM " & Mailbox & Totals & _
       " WHERE(Total.UnitCode=" & Sheets("Pipe Cleaning").Range("C4") & " ) )"
```

But it may be cleaner to just get the date value and then format in VBA:

```
sSql = " (SELECT MAX(StockDate) StockDate FROM " & Mailbox & Totals & _
       " WHERE(Total.UnitCode=" & Sheets("Pipe Cleaning").Range("C4") & " ) "

.. execute SQL, store result in dtDate

sDate = Format(dtDate, "dd/mm/yy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the format in a MAX statement.  You have to specify the months as caps **MM** though.

Sample:

```
Select Max(Format(mydatefield, 'dd/MM/yy')) from mytable
```